# How to initialize an object inside a list initializer without using anonymous objects?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list and I initialized it using an initializer list and inside that list I want to create a new object and I do not want that object to be anonymous. Can anybody  help me with that?
My code looks like this:

```
Product product=new Product(){
OrderProductAttributes = new List<OrderProductAttribute>
     {
         //initialize an object(I do not want it to be anonymous)
        }
    }
```

Comment: "not anonymous" in what way? You won't be able to use it (or even define a variable) aside from the collection initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you mean by anonymous, but you can definitely do a concrete instantiation during initialization.

```
Product product=new Product(){
OrderProductAttributes = new List<OrderProductAttribute>()
     {
         //initialize an object(I do not want it to be anonymous)
         new OrderProductAttributes() { Property1 = 10, Property2 = false... },
         new OrderProductAttributes() { Property1 = 20 Property2 = false... },
    }};
```

You can also name the variables and add them:

```
OrderProductAttributes test = new ...;
OrderProdcutAttributes test2 = new ...;
Product product=new Product(){
OrderProductAttributes = new List<OrderProductAttribute>()
     {
         //initialize an object(I do not want it to be anonymous)
         test,
         test2,
    }};
```

**Note** This code needs to be in an instanced method (say, the constructor) and won't work in the member declaration unless `test` and `test2` are marked `static`.

Comment: I tried your second approach and got this error: Error 14 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ProductMapping.Business.Controller.productAttribute'

Comment: @Shary Sorry, I assumed that was in a function. Yes, to do the second method you need to perform the initialization in an instanced method *or* mark the variables as `static`. You will usually just do the initialization in the constructor in this sort of case.

Comment: I did the initialization, but still get this error.

Comment: @Shary If you are getting *that* error, you are doing this as a field initializer, which means everything you reference has to be static. Could you describe better what you actually did/changed?

Comment: @Shary Right, because *the things you are initializing with* have to be static. Mark `test` as static and it will work. Again, not the *recommended* way (you should only use `static` if you know what you're doing), but it will compile.

Comment: I did it.Thanks! I was wondering what is the fastest way to learn c# if you can help with that as well?

Comment: @Shary There isn't really a "fastest" way. In my opinion, the only way to truly "learn" a language is to do projects in it, and actually *use* the various pieces you need. Thats the only way to get all the gotchas, side-effects and so on that aren't obvious from documentation/books. Of course, that approach is a lot easier when you have experience programming :). The MSDN docs are very useful for finding specific controls, functions, etc. if you already have a starting point.

Comment: Now I am having another problem. I could initialze that OrderProductAttribute list and put items inside it but now what if I want to instantiate anotherobject in test and test2? How does that work?

Comment: @Shary Not sure what you mean. Sounds like another SO question (make sure to include the code!). Given that I'm not sure, make sure to also include a detailed description of what you are trying to do (maybe some pseudocode).

Comment: I have the list   `OrderProductAttributes = new List<OrderProductAttribute>
       {
          orderProductAttribute }` and   `static OrderProductAttribute orderProductAttribute = new OrderProductAttribute()
        { productAttribute = new  ProductAttribute()
            { attributeType=new AttributeType(),
    // but this class will not be instantiated and the orderProduct attribute will be null  }  };` How can I instantiate the `attributeType` object?

Comment: @Shary The error lies elsewhere. Nothing is inherently wrong with that code. I would post it as a full SO question, making sure to include any errors you see.

Comment: Actually there is no error. AttributeType object is not instantiated. I am writing the output in a json file and what I see is that inside the `orderProductAttribute` list, there is  `productAttribute` but it is null and it does not show `attributeType` at all.

Comment: @Shary First, look in a debugger, not an output file, as that removes other potential issues. Second, there is something you aren't showing. Initializers don't just randomly "not run". Seeing the fully formatted code (in a new post) could also help someone or me diagnose it. Feel free to post a link to the new question when you have it ready.

Comment: Here is the link. I will let you know the debugging results once I did it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994982/initialize-nested-classes-in-a-list