# Initialize nested classes in a list

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a list called `OrderProductAttributes` and I initialzed it like the following:

```
OrderProductAttributes = new List<OrderProductAttribute>
   {orderProductAttribute }
```

I have to two other nested classes in the `OrderProductAttribute` and I am trying to instantiate them like the following:

```
static OrderProductAttribute orderProductAttribute = new OrderProductAttribute()
    {
        productAttribute = new ProductAttribute()
        {
            attributeType=new AttributeType()
        }
    };
```

I want to see them as a json file and once I open the output json file I see the following:

```
"OrderProductAttributes":{"["productAttribute":null]"}
```

I was wondering why the `attributeType` was not created in the `productAttribute` since I have initiated it already?

I was expecting to see

```
"OrderProductAttributes":{"["productAttribute":"attributeType":""]"}
```

Comment: Yes! It's a public property.

Comment: Is there an array in there? Why would you expect the `[]` syntax?

Comment: The `OrderProductAttributes` is a list.

Comment: I see, it seems like there would be an extra piece in your output indicating an object (of type `OrderProductAttribute`) but that doesn't explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Consider providing samples that resemble valid JSON. Especially one you "expecting to see" is very confusing.

Comment: Lacking a complete code example, it's not possible to answer. _Maybe_ you are initializing the variables in the wrong order, or maybe there's some other problem. For that matter, maybe the object is in fact initialized properly, and you just have a bug in the part that writes the pseudo-"JSON" file (I hesitate to call it actual JSON).

Comment: The output should be `"OrderProductAttribute": [ {"ProductAttribute": "attributeType":" something"}]` But I am not getting the `attributeType` section.  What I provided is a valid json, what is wrong with that?